# I'm trying to enter login information into internet explorer 9 using VBA, after veiwing a litany of posts I am still having trouble

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

The website is https://portal.care360.com/care360/care360.login. By right clicking and selecting veiw source code I can see the HTML code. I have also isolated the section of the code that I need to work with using the developer tools. (It actually highlights the item when you click on the code that cooresponds to it.)

I've added references to

- Microsoft Internet Options
- Microsoft HTML Object Library

I have also included my VBA code that makes different attempts to enter something in the fields.

```
Dim shellWins As ShellWindows
  Dim appIE As InternetExplorer
  Dim Doc As Object
  Dim sURL As String
  Dim UserN As Variant 'MSHTML.IHTMLElement
  Dim PW As Variant
  Dim Element As Object
  Dim btnInput As Object
  Dim ElementCol As Object
  Dim Link As Object
  Dim strCountBody As String
  Dim lStartPos As Long
  Dim lEndPos As Long
  Dim TextIWant As String
  Dim i As Integer

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set shellWins = New ShellWindows

  'Check if Internet Explorer is already open and use the open instance if it is
  If shellWins.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To shellWins.Count - 1
              If shellWins.Item(i).Name = "Windows Internet Explorer" Then
                    ' Get IE
                    Set appIE = shellWins.Item(i)
              End If
        Next
  Else
    ' Create IE if not already open
    Set appIE = New InternetExplorer
    appIE.visible = True
  End If

   'set URL
  sURL = "https://portal.care360.com/care360/care360.login"

  With appIE
      .Navigate sURL
      .visible = True
  End With

  ' loop until the page finishes loading
  Do While appIE.Busy
        VBA.DoEvents
  Loop

  'Different things I've tried...
  If VBA.InStr(1, appIE.document.Title, "Care360") Then
        appIE.document.getElementById ("loginBoxNew")
        appIE.document.getElementById ("loginFormOnline")
        Set ElementCol = appIE.document.getElementsByName("j_username")
  End If

   UserN = appIE.document.getElementsByName("j_username")
   Set ElementCol = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("FORM")
   If Not UserN Is Nothing Then
        UserN(0).Value = "my username"
  End If

  Set Doc = appIE.document
  If VBA.IsNull(Doc) Then
  VBA.DoEvents
  End If

  appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("j_username").Value = "mypassword"
  appIE.document.getElementById ("LoginFormOnline")
  With appIE.document.forms("LoginFormOnline")
        .All("j_username").Value = "myUsername"
  End With
  appIE.document.forms("LoginFormOnline").All("j_username").Value = "mypassword"
  Set UserN = appIE.document.getElementsByName("j_username")
```

I think the two text field, username and password are named "j_username" and "j_password", however they don't seem to have IDs so I can't use getElementByID. getElementByTag seems difficult because there are a lot of  tags in the HTML. If you can show me some code that works I would be so greatful. I have posted the relevant HTML code below.

```
<form onsubmit="if(typeof loginSubmit == 'function') { return loginSubmit(); } else { return true; }" style="display: inline;" method="post" action="Care360SecurityCheck" id="LoginFormOnline" name="LoginFormOnline" autocomplete="off">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>User ID</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" maxlength="40" size="20" name="j_username"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Password</td>
                                    <td style="display:none"><input style="display:none" type="password" name="foilautofill1"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="password" size="20" name="j_password"></td>
                                    <td style="display:none"><input style="display:none" type="password" name="foilautofill2"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="auditStyle">Reminder: Password is case-sensitive.</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td class="loginButtonCell">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="button" name="btnLogin">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>
                                                                                                <div class="rightfloat">
                                                    <a href="PasswordReset.jsp">Forgot or Reset Password?</a>
                                                </div>
                                                                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
With appIE.document

   .getElementsByName("j_username")(0).Value = "myUserName"
   .getElementsByName("j_password")(0).Value = "myPassword"
   .getElementsByName("btnLogin")(0).Click

End With
```

`getElementsByName()` returns a set of elements (even if there's only one match in the document) so you have to address the first element in the collection (which is zero-based) and not the collection itself.